# How does register_post_type know how and which function to use from the add_action function?

Tags: custom-post-types

[This](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) is from the WordPress site, and I can't find my answer in the documentation.  When I issue the `register_post_type`, how does it know which function to use?  I know the `init` action was populated with the custom hook `codex_book_init`, but when I look at register_post_type.  It just has "book":

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );

register_post_type( 'book', $args );
```

How does this work?  Not asking about all the `$args`, only the one(s) that matter for this question.

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );
/**
 * Register a book post type.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
 */
function codex_book_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Book', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No books found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing between function and hook. `register_post_type()` is a function, not a hook.

When you are using `register_post_type( 'book', $args )`, you are calling the `register_post_type()` function to create a Custom Post Type named `book`.

`register_post_type()` needs to be used on the `init` hook which is fired at the beginning of wordpress initialisation, that's why you are using `add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' )` and using `register_post_type()` there.

Comment: .  Thanks.  I didn't know it wasn't a hook or there was even a distinction.

Answer (score 2):

book is what you're naming the post type you're registering. Then it's referencing the `$args` array to define properties for the the custom post type. It could just as easily be written as so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );

function codex_book_init() {
  register_post_type(
    'book',
     array( // Arguments
       'labels'             => array(
         'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Book', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'new_item'           => __( 'New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'view_item'          => __( 'View Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'not_found'          => __( 'No books found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
         'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
       ),
       'public'             => true,
       'publicly_queryable' => true,
       'show_ui'            => true,
       'show_in_menu'       => true,
       'query_var'          => true,
       'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
       'capability_type'    => 'post',
       'has_archive'        => true,
       'hierarchical'       => false,
       'menu_position'      => null,
       'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
     )
   );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting it differently.  You put function up top which makes sense or it is easier to read anyway.  I see both $args and this way now.  Thanks.